# Datepicker and modals does not work on IE and Edge

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

Im trying tow rite a webpage using both datepicker and admindesigns template. But when i start using IE or Edge browser every javascript i have wirtten stops working. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript " src="vendor/jquery/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom/datepicker-pl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/plugins/daterange/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //Datepicker
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "pl" ] );

        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
        showButtonPanel: false
        });
```

Whats more even if i stop using datepicker if i try to include:

```
<script type="text/javascript " src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
```

Scripts suddenly stops working. It would be very helpful if someine would help me with this one.

Comment: try renaming the file "bootstrap.min.js" to "boostrap.js" and reference it again in your webpage. Apply the same for jquery-ui too.

Comment: It didnt help for datepicker, but scripts without datepicker started to work. Sadly, modals still does not work.

Comment: I am not seeing any reference for jquery...? if it is needed in your project, try adding it to the top (just above jquery-ui)

Comment: It is added. My bad its working on 1.11.1 jquery